# mpdf div 100% height of container

Tags: php, mpdf

Using mpdf is there a way to make a child div with the same height as it's parent i.e 100%?

Normally I'd just have the parent positioned relative with the child positioned absolute with 100% height but with mpdf all absolutely positioned elements are positioned according to the page not the container. Is there a way round this?